# Python app to read from webpage and input to windows-application. Can python handle that?

Tags: selenium

So i have been using Selenium via Python via chromewebdriver, and love it. Learning prosess has been great and has managed to greate few bots (that use brower to naviagate)

But now  i'm facing a different problem.

I need to read from webpage and type it into a 3th party application that i have running in my windows PC.

I assume Selenium cannot handle this? Is there any app that can via Python?

Thanks!

Comment: To deal with windows GUI apps, I like Autoit. (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)  Simple, lightwaight, but powerful and flexible enough. And it can compile exe files, which you can use easily with CLI from python or from anything else. It's like selenium for web, but not for web =)

Comment: Thanks for this! Can the Autoit-script read from the webpage or should i pass the data from selenium to Autoit?

Comment: It works with such things as window handles, window controls, their props, not with DOM. as selenium does. I think, even if it can, it is bad idea to feed it with DOM. It can handle GUI's well, and selenium does its best with web. Your task seem to use them both. It's extremely easy to learn, maybe of great embedded help with samples for any word you type.